# css footer background didn't shows properly in html5

Tags: css, html

Here is my css code:

```
.footer{
    clear:both;
    background:url('../img/footer-bg.jpg');
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer-left{
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}

.footer-right{
    float:right;    
    width:50%;
}
.footer-nav .list-1 {
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-align: center; 
}
.footer-nav .list-2 {
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-align: center; 
}
.footer-nav ul li{
    display:inline;
    padding:8px;
}
.copyright{

    font-size:13px;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Here is my JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/3jet0dfu/12/

May i know how to set background image to 100% attached with window screen.and the footer content need to display right of image.

Now i added `<hr />` line for footer-left and footer-right at the top and bottom.

But it shows at the top only, Can anybody help me exact css style to fix this.

I need look like this http://s30.postimg.org/gvqtdrmqp/article_page4.jpg.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to css

```
header,section{
margin:0 auto;
width:939px;}
```

and edit body css like this

```
body{
font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
 }
```

this working page [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yugi47/6d27bd0s/)

Answer (score 0):

remove the 2

---

and replace the following html and add the css

```
<div id="footer-holder">
        <div class="footer-left">
        <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/itr24b7s9/footer1.png" alt="footer-image" />
        <div class="footer-content">
            <p class="footer-title">.NET Training</p>
            <p class="footer-pgf">Less of boring theory! Hands on programming is our training methodology! You'll love it.<p>
            <a href="#">learn more </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-right">
        <img src="http://s18.postimg.org/gl8a98bah/footer2.png" alt="footer-image" />
        <div class="footer-content">
            <p class="footer-title">Shopify Expert at $20/hour</p>
            <p class="footer-pgf">Unique custom made shopify theme and tweakss. Strat selling online with stunning eCommerce storefronts created using the Shopify CMS</p>
            <a href="#">learn more</a>  
        </div>
    </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>


#footer-holder{
-webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
-o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;
border-left:none;
border-right:none;
width: 100%;
}
```